# is it a good pratice to store authentication data in neo4j nodes?

Tags: authentication, neo4j

This may seem to be an ingenuous question but I searched for examples without finding anything about it. So, is it a good practice to store authentication data such as usernames and passwords in a neo4j database? I use to embed but I ask for the general case.
Ps. I don't want this to become an opinion-based discussion, I was just wondering whether there are some technical aspects that make this operation not safe or anyway not so good.

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for here: Opinions on using a graph database vs other database types, for storing credentials? If that's the case, that wouldn't fit here, since... you'll just get opinions. Could you perhaps edit your question to ask something more specific and objective?

Comment: Actually i dont want opinions, i just want to know if there are some technical reasons not to store credential on a neo4j database

Comment: You should be fine, as long as you hash and salt your passwords. And make sure to communicate over an https connection with authentication with the db or in a trusted network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be fine, as long as you hash and salt your passwords correctly.

And make sure to communicate over an [https connection with authentication](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/security-server.html) with the db 
or in a trusted network.

Comment: Ok, so I'll have the same problem I could have with any other database, in other words There's no a particular reason not to store credentials in neo4j db, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can store authentication data in Neo4j nodes with no issues at all, as long as you properly encrypt the passwords and follow other guidelines. A structure of Nodes and Relationships is a great way to handle complex authentication and authorisation data. This should help -> [Neo4j Access Management](https://neo4j.com/use-cases/identity-and-access-management/)

Comment: Links tend to expire over time. Could you provide the relevant information from that link (e.g. quoted excerpts) as part of your answer?